# Downloading image from url - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting an issue where I can't create a folder with a similar name as a file inside the folder.

For instance if the image contains the name

`apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty.jpg`

I'll get the error: (I seperated the directory path  for readability)

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/PictureGallery/`

`apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty/`

`apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty.-1.jpg'`

However if I use half of that folder name to something like...

`apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse`

I won't get an error. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

**Downloading the image:**

```
import os

import requests


def download(url: str, dest_folder: str):
    print("DESTINATION FOLDER: " + dest_folder)
    if not os.path.exists(dest_folder):
        os.makedirs(dest_folder)

    filename = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "_")  # be careful with file names
    file_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, filename)
    print("File path: " + file_path)

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.ok:
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()
                    os.fsync(f.fileno())
    else:  # HTTP status code 4XX/5XX
        print("Download failed: status code {}\n{}".format(r.status_code, r.text))
```

**And the main.py:**

```
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from downloader import download

url = 'https://urltoimage.com/123456/apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty/'
model_name = 'Coolname'

album_name = ' '.join(url.split("/")).split()[-1] #apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty
print("Album name: " + album_name)
location = "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/" + model_name + "/" + album_name + "/"

print('Location: ' + location) #C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/Coolname/apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty/

reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    if album_name in link.get('src').lower():
        print(link.get('src'))
        download(link.get('src'), location)
```

For the line in my main.py:

`location = "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/" + model_name + "/" + album_name + "/"`
the album name would normally be extracted from the url so...

`apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty`

This causes the error to be thrown.

HOWEVER when I change it to anything else...

such as

`location = "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/" + model_name + "/" + "anything5"+ "/"`

or

`location = "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/" + model_name + "/" + "apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse"+ "/"`

the download will work without any errors thrown. I have no idea what's causing this issue.

The error is thrown at `line 18` in the `downloader.py`

`with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:`

Full error:

```
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/Coolname/apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty/apple-banana-carrot-dog-electric-fish-gorilla-horse-igloo-jackrabbit-kangaroo-long-maze-nickel-octopus-pretty.-1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you using windows you need to use `\` instead of `/`

For example: `file_path = "C:\\Users\\arter\\filename.ext"` or `file_path = "C:\Users\arter\filename.ext"`

Comment: It works with ```/``` the issue is that if I use a folder name that is similar to the ```image``` name im trying to download, it doesn't work